# How to add properties to a class at runtime in c# - From JSON file

Tags: c#, class, dynamic, properties

I want to create a class that can dynamically assign properties at runtime.

Brief summary of what I am doing: I am creating a program that will dynamically parse XML files for different software and display the info in well organized tables using MVC. Every software app is defined in my JSON file and has certain attributes to it.

JSON file example:

```
    "AMZsoftware": {
     "APP1": {
     "ResponseTime": "2412",
     "Location": [ "tmd_7609", "tmd_61573" ],
     "Properties": ["Speed", "Capacity", "Security"]
      },
      "APP2": {
      "ResponseTime": "1712",
      "Location": [ "LT_13", "LT_00" ],
      "Properties": ["Speed", "Resilience", "Security"]   
      },
     "APP3": {
      "ResponseTime": "0117",
      "Location": [ "AP_99", "AP_47" ],
      "Properties": ["Database", "WorkFlow", "LZSettings"]   
      },
     };
```

This is just a tiny piece of my JSON file but mainly if you look at the properties section, there's a list of attributes. Those are the attributes that need to be assigned at runtime. I have different classes that are of those types that will handle retrieving and storing data for me.

As you can see, some of the properties are repeated but some are different and I need to be able to account for those differences. I'm storing the properties from the JSON file in a list of strings.

I have read articles about using dictionaries, but is there a way I can create a completely new class with dynamic properties?

When the user chooses to see data regarding APP1, I want to create a class with the properties listed and then my program will handle the parsing and things normally.

Once the information is stored in this dynamic class, I'd pass it to the view and print the data. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: The attributes are a Dictionary, Add a dictionary to your class

Comment: @TheGeneral oh okay I see, let me try that. New to c# and MVC so a little confused with all the possible options.

Answer (score 0):

From this:  "I have different classes that are of those types that will handle retrieving and storing data for me."

If I'm reading it correctly it sounds like you already have classes that operate on the properties. You could create an interface that all those classes are based on, then use a Class Factory to return the class that operates on a given "property" by passing the property name into the factory.

To start with, do a web search for "C# Class Factory" and there will be loads of info on how the Class Factory pattern works.

Essentially a Class Factory has an Interface, one or more classes that implement the Interface, and a Factory that returns an instance of a class that implements the Interface. An application can then use all those pieces to perform some task.

Here is a small example I cobbled together.

IMathOperation.cs

```
// The interface that all factory classes must implement:
interface IMathOperation
{
    string getName();
    string performOperation(int a, int b);
}
```

Classes that implement the Interface:

Add.cs

```
public class Add : IMathOperation
{
    public string getName()
    {
        return "Addition";
    }

    public string performOperation(int a, int b)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} + {1} = {2}", a, b, a+b);
    }

}
```

Subtract.cs

```
public class Subtract : IMathOperation
{
    public string getName()
    {
        return "Subtraction";
    }

    public string performOperation(int a, int b)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} - {1} = {2}", a, b, a-b);
    }

}
```

Multiply.cs

```
public class Multiply : IMathOperation
{
    public string getName()
    {
        return "Multiplication";
    }

    public string performOperation(int a, int b)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} * {1} = {2}", a, b, a*b);
    }

}
```

Divide.cs

```
public class Divide : IMathOperation
{
    public string getName()
    {
        return "Division";
    }

    public string performOperation(int a, int b)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} / {1} = {2}", a, b, b != 0? ((float)((float)a / (float)b)).ToString() : "Divide by zero error");
    }

}
```

MathFactory.cs

```
class MathFactory
{

    public static IMathOperation getFactory(string mathOp)
    {
        switch (mathOp.ToUpper())
        {
            case "ADD":
            return new Add();

            case "SUB":
            return new Subtract();

            case "MUL":
            return new Multiply();

            case "DIV":
            return new Divide();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;

namespace ClassFactory_C_Sharp {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IMathOperation op;

            Console.WriteLine("Hello Math Factory!\n");

            // try all the class factories

            op = MathFactory.getFactory("Add");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", op.getName(), op.performOperation(2,3)));

            op = MathFactory.getFactory("Sub");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", op.getName(), op.performOperation(2,3)));

            op = MathFactory.getFactory("Mul");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", op.getName(), op.performOperation(2,3)));

            op = MathFactory.getFactory("Div");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", op.getName(), op.performOperation(2,3)));

            // try one more divide that causes error
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", op.getName(), op.performOperation(2,0)));
        }
    } }
```

The output:

```
Hello Math Factory!

Addition: 2 + 3 = 5
Subtraction: 2 - 3 = -1
Multiplication: 2 * 3 = 6
Division: 2 / 3 = 0.6666667
Division: 2 / 0 = Divide by zero error
```

Comment: Yes I do gave classes that operate on the properties. I'm new to c# and MVC so if you have any articles you can send me on class factories, that'd be great :) I'll look into it! I also heard about expandoobject? I just have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

[`ExpandoObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject) could be a good option for you. It can be used as follows.

```
dynamic app2    = new ExpandoObject();
app2.Speed      = 2.54d;
app2.Resilience = 99;
app2.Security   = "High";
```

You can add as many properties of any type to the object you have created.

I have a [blog post](https://jonathancrozier.com/blog/time-to-reflect-how-to-add-properties-to-a-c-sharp-object-dynamically-at-runtime) with more information on `ExpandoObject` where I also discuss an alternative approach using reflection and I have a sample project on GitHub which reads the dynamic property definitions and values from a JSON file.